# How to convert Json value to Boolean while inserting into table?

Tags: json, rest, jersey, boolean

I have following JSON structure.

```
{
"activeInd":"1"
}
```

I am converting String to Boolean value while inserting into DTO object

```
setDTOActiveInd(request.getActiveInd() == "1")
```

When I verify the table it has the ActiveInd as "0" which is false

My test cases are passed when sending "1" and retrieving true from table
but not sure why it is not able to convert "1" from JSON to boolean "true" ??

Comment: In the case that you can modify the JSON Format, you can use integers or booleans  instead of strings. Check this link, which is the JSON standar: https://www.json.org/

Comment: How do you use Jersey (and JAX-RS?) to convert this JSON into a structure with a boolean value?

Answer (score -1):

A boolean is not an integer; 1 and 0 are not boolean values in Code. You'll need to convert them explicitly:

```
boolean activeInd= (1 == jsonObject.getInt("activeInd"));
```

Comment: This is not entirely true, boolean is a synonym for tinyint so `(bool)0` will return false and `(bool)1` will return true